[NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.]
I am getting the error [NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.]
I am using Next Js 14.2 version. We are using Amplify v6 gen 1 and I am trying to get the user session in my middleware so that we can authenticate users.
I have done all the steps like amplify init and amplify pull etc.
I have followed this documentation from aws amplify https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react/build-a-backend/server-side-rendering/nextjs/
This is my middleware.tsx
//@ts-nocheck
import {
  fetchAuthSession,
  getCurrentUser,
  fetchUserAttributes,
} from "aws-amplify/auth/server";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { runWithAmplifyServerContext } from "./utils/amplifyServerUtils";
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  try {
    let data = {};
    const authenticated = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
      nextServerContext: { request, response },
      operation: async (contextSpec: any) => {
        try {
          const session = await fetchAuthSession(contextSpec);
          if(session.tokens){

            data = await getCurrentUser(contextSpec);
            let data1 = await fetchUserAttributes(contextSpec);
            data = Object.assign(data, data1);
          }
          // console.log("user data from amplify");
          // console.log(data);
          // console.log(data)

          return session.tokens !== undefined;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return false;
        }
      },
    });
    if (!authenticated) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
    }

    const headers = new Headers(request.headers);

    headers.set("userData", JSON.stringify(data));
    return NextResponse.next({ request: { headers } });
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.log("Error in middleware")
    console.log(error.message)
    return NextResponse.json({error},{status:405})
  }
}
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/api/:path*",  
    "/api/imageCID",
    "/api/ownerDetails",
    "/api/customerDetails",
    "/api/rentalDetails",
    "/api/requirementsDetails",
    "/api/specificationDetails",
    "/api/userProfile",
    "/api/imageCID",
    "/api/basicDetails",
    "/api/geocode",
    "/api/addressSearch",
    "/ViewOwnPost",
    "/ViewPost",
    "/ViewListing",
    "/posty",
    "/create-profile"
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
  ],
};

Below is my amplifyServerUtils
import { createServerRunner } from '@aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs';
import config from './amplifyconfiguration';

export const { runWithAmplifyServerContext } = createServerRunner({
  config
});

Can anyone help me out with this error
I am trying to get the session from amplify auth at server side. And expecting it to provide me the token and user details
